# Bankruptcy tag definition

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I noticed that the [bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bankruptcy) tag has no wiki currently, and was considering editing one; but wanted to make sure I had a solid understanding of what it should mean here.

Given this is a personal finance site, should [bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bankruptcy) be used solely to discuss personal bankruptcy (ie, questions about the consequences of filing, how to file, when to file, how to recover, etc.)?  Or should it include other things related to the general term (such as discussing bankrupt companies, such as a question about trading stock in a bankrupt company, or a question about bankruptcy of a trading firm)?

Answer (score 4):

You should stick to the personal finance angle for sure, but according to how we have been using it:

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bankruptcy

It is used on the site to discuss personal bankruptcy and well as the impact of companies going bankrupt.  I think you have a chance for some badges as well as adding clarity to the topics.

**Here is my suggestion:**

Make the wiki about [bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bankruptcy), [personal-bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-bankruptcy) and [business-bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-bankruptcy).  You can re-tag the appropriate questions.  If you can just add a tag that is more specific, great.  If you need to replace a tag, leave out the general bankruptcy in favor of the specific one.

*I wouldn't jump on doing anything until the rest of the community weighs for a vote on if I am a dunderhead or a genius*

Comment: The only question I would have is whether [tag:bankruptcy] is better as a single tag that has relatively little meaning (ie, the tag wiki instructs to add an additional tag of personal or business/corporate) or if it makes more sense to make [tag:bankruptcy] a synonym of personal bankruptcy (with instructions at the start of the wiki for using the other tag for corporate bankruptcies).

Comment: There's also a difference between bankruptcy of one's own small business (sole proprietorship, partnership, or private corp.), and how that might affect one's finances, vs. bankruptcy of a corporation in which one has, say, invested as a shareholder. Perhaps 'business-bankruptcy' for the former, and something else for the latter? Or is this too fine-grained?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea [tag:personal-bankruptcy], [tag:business-bankruptcy] for 'your own business', and [tag:corporate-bankruptcy] for corporate bankruptcy that is not owned by the person asking (or otherwise directly involved in)?